# Ending my sentence with "seven"

Tags: word-choice

Can I end my sentence with a number?
"My friend loves tattoos. She has seven. She's going to get another one."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a problem.  "seven" is understood in context to mean "seven tattoos". There is a natural promotion from numeral or determiner to a pronoun.

Compare with the pronomial use of "some" in the following example.

> I like cake. I'm going to eat some.

Comment: Does "some" mean "a little" in this case but in other situations it can to refer to an indefinite amount as in "I am going to eat some sweets" and "I am going to buy some apples"?

Comment: Antonia, why should 'some cake' be different from 'some sweets'? In the case of cake, presumably 'one or more slices'.